# SQLite3 : Assigned directly the query result to a struct in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I searched in the Web but could not find any solutions for my problem.
I have a table user_info with fields user_id, username, password.
Also I have a struct st_user_info.

```
typedef struct {
     int userId;
     char* userName;
     char* password;
} T_USERINFO;
T_USERINFO tUserInfo[10];
```

Now, i want that the my query result from sqlite3_step command or any, will be directly assigned to this struct tUserInfo[index]. 
Is there a way to do on this way...? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for high-level language features such as [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) in C, so the short answer is no. SQLite cannot automatically populate your structure for you. You have to retrieve the results of your query the normal way, and assign the values to the structure yourself.

Comment: Well, thanks for the time. It seems that I have to assign each column to the members of my struct one by one. Or is there any way to lessen or shorten my codes somehow rather than assigning to struct members one by one?

Comment: No, sorry. You can wrap it all up in a helper function so it's all nicely hidden, but you can't escape the fact that at some level, you have to write code to fill each structure member with the relevant data from the query.